# Whether numpy array is immutable?

Tags: numpy

Arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

Arr + 10 returns a new np array with 10 added to each cell

Original array isn't affected

Whereas Arr+=100 does the same but mutates the original array.

Does this mean numpy array is not immutable? Or is it shallow/deep copy?

I'm confused because operations like Arr[0]=100 mutate the original array?

Comment: A numpy array is a lot like a list.  In general it is mutable - you can change the values of its elements, as you show.  But many operations produce a new array instead of mutating the array itself.  But when you spend much time with the basic documentation, you'll learn about the import distinction between a `view` and `copy`.  A `view` is a new array, but one which shares the underlying data buffer (have you read enough basics to know how an array is stored?)

Answer (score 0):

numpy arrays are mutable.

`__iadd__()` modifies the array inplace.

try:

```py
Arr += 10
```

`__add__()` will create a new array.